# android - Change boolean value on onOptionsItemSelected

Tags: java, android

I am developping an app displaying different movies, with three options on my menu : top rated, most popular and favorites.

I control the movies displayed through boolean, in this way :

- isFavorite = true && is topRated = false => display the favorites
- isFavorite = false && topRated = true => display the topRated
- isFavorite = false && topRated = false => display the most popular

So far, when I set the value manually on the OnCreate(), it works !

My issue comes when I try to change this value by clicking on the differents options of the menu... it displays the same list of movies independently of the option I click on.

Here is my onOptionItemSelected() method :

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int itemId = item.getItemId();


    switch (itemId){
        case R.id.most_popular:
            setFavorite(false);
            setTopRated(false);
            movieAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            Context context = MainActivity.this;
            String textToShow = "Sorted by most popular";
            Toast.makeText(context, textToShow, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case R.id.highest_rated:
            setFavorite(false);
            setTopRated(true);

            movieAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            context = MainActivity.this;
            textToShow = "Sorted by rate";
            Toast.makeText(context, textToShow, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case R.id.favorites:
            setFavorite(true);
            setTopRated(false);

            movieAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            context = MainActivity.this;
            textToShow = "Here is your favorites list";
            Toast.makeText(context, textToShow, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        default:
            Log.w(TAG, "Menu selection is not handled. ItemId;" + itemId);

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please don't rely on external links, add your code  in the post and we'll try to find an answer

Comment: The onCreate only load favorites movies. Where do you implement the filtering logic?

Comment: @M.Situation, thanks, I am new here and I did not thought about that. I just edited my message.

@W

Comment: @WalterPalladino, I implement it on my AynckTask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the adapter to get new set of data, you need to clear the the old data before passing in the new ones and then notify the adapter when you're done. You can do that with this `movieAdapter.clear();`... Here's how to implement it:

```
    case R.id.highest_rated:
//Clear the adapter whenever this highest rated movie is clicked
                movieAdapter.clear(); //Clear the adapter whenever this highest rated movie is clicked
                setFavorite(false);
                setTopRated(true);

                movieAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                context = MainActivity.this;
                textToShow = "Sorted by rate";
                Toast.makeText(context, textToShow, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
```

Comment: Thanks ! I haven't seen your answer but I just figured out the same thing :)

Answer (score 0):

I succeed to resolve my issue ! Here are the modifications, on my MakeTheQuery() method and onOptionItemSelected ;

```
private void makeTheQuery() {
    movies.clear();
    isFavorite = isFavorite();
    isTopRated = isTopRated();

    URL SearchUrl;
    if (!isTopRated) {
        SearchUrl = NetworkUtils.buildUrl();
    }else{
        SearchUrl = NetworkUtils.buildUrlTopRated();
    }
    new TheMovieAsyncTask().execute(SearchUrl);
}
```

and

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int itemId = item.getItemId();


    switch (itemId){
        case R.id.most_popular:
            setFavorite(false);
            setTopRated(false);
            movieAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            makeTheQuery();

            Context context = MainActivity.this;
            String textToShow = "Sorted by most popular";
            Toast.makeText(context, textToShow, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case R.id.highest_rated:
            setFavorite(false);
            setTopRated(true);

            movieAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            makeTheQuery();


            context = MainActivity.this;
            textToShow = "Sorted by rate";
            Toast.makeText(context, textToShow, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case R.id.favorites:
            setFavorite(true);
            setTopRated(false);

            movieAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            makeTheQuery();

            context = MainActivity.this;
            textToShow = "Here is your favorites list";
            Toast.makeText(context, textToShow, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        default:
            Log.w(TAG, "Menu selection is not handled. ItemId;" + itemId);

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```